# How to crop text instead of getting ellipsis ("...") in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm curious, does anybody know how to prevent SwiftUI from replacing text that doesn't fit in a view with an ellipsis? I'm trying to reproduce the exact look-and-feel of the swipe-to-delete controls in the iOS Reminders app, and if you look at how that behaves, you see that it simply crops the text when there isn't enough space to display them fully. When I try to reproduce this, the text gets replaced with ellipses ("..."). Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Here's how it looks in Reminders:

[image]

And here's how my version looks:

[image]

Here is the code for my version:

```swift
struct CroppedText: View {
    var text: String
    var color: Color
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)  // How to avoid the "..."?
            .lineLimit(1)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(color)
    }
}

struct TripleText: View {
    @State private var totalWidth = 120.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                CroppedText(text: "Details", color: .secondary)
                CroppedText(text: "Flag", color: .orange)
                CroppedText(text: "Delete", color: .red)
            }
            .frame(width: totalWidth, height: 50)
            
            HStack {
                Text("Width: ")
                Slider(value: $totalWidth, in: 1...300)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Thinking about it, it seems the solution must include a mechanism for preventing the text from being centred in the space available to them, if the space is too small. It almost seems as if this is pointing to a solution involving an elaborate `ZStack` instead of the straight-forward `HStack`. Perhaps we aren't cropping the text, but rather mostly layering them (though a top-level `.clipped()` would still be needed). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can establish the footprint in a hidden base view, then show the actual text in an overlay. The text in the overlay is shown with `.fixedSize()` , which stops it being truncated with ellipses. If there is not enough space, it simply gets cut off at end of frame.

Like this:

```swift
struct CroppedText: View {
    var text: String
    var color: Color
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .hidden()
            .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(text)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .background(color)
    }
}
```

[image: Truncated]

*EDIT* The frame that sets `maxWidth` should be set *after* the overlay, so that if there is any surplus space (when displaying a short string), the result is still centered:

[image: Hello]

Comment: Brilliant! That's perfect. Thank you, especially for including the reasoning.

Comment: You're welcome Thanks for accepting the answer.